# Detect whether android device is connected to the pc using java

Tags: java, android

How can i detect whether an android device is connected to the pc using java.I am creating a dynamic web project and in one jsp page i want to check whether an android device is connected to client machine.the client machine is assumed to have no android SDK installed.

Any help will be appreciated.

I want  result exactly the same in google play,as it shows in the below picture
[image]

Comment: [check this](http://today.java.net/article/2006/07/05/java-and-usb) but question seems crazy.lol

Answer (score 0):

You can use ADB. It is located in the SDK folder.

```
adb devices
```

prints a  list of the connected devices.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to grab the shell using java on windows and try adb devices as cypressious suggested.

```
try {
        mProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("adb devices > C:\Users\status.txt");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printstacktrace   }
    osStream = new DataOutputStream(mProcess.getOutputStream());
```

After this you can simply parse status.txt file and see if devices are connected.

Comment: I am creating a dynamic web project,and in one jsp page i want to check whether the client machine has an android device connected to it,so client machine is assumed to have no android SDK,hence no adb